# What does HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463 mean?

Tags: php, image, http

Basically, I'm creating a script which will edit an image and will only show part of that image but I keep getting this error **'HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463'**. I've tried searching on W3 but I can't seem to find the **error code 463** and I've tried looking for it on here but the same thing, I can't seem to find it. If you can help me out it will be appreciated.

**Thank you.**

**Code Used:**

```
// Start Vars
$habbo = $_GET['habbo'];
$hdirection = $_GET['head_direction'];
$size = $_GET['size'];

// Define the URL
$url  = "https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=".$habbo."&action=non&gesture=non&direction=3&head_direction=".$hdirection."&size=".$size."&img_format=gif";

// Define vars
$habbo = imagecreatefromgif($url);
$head = imagecreatefromgif("./head.gif");
$patch = imagecreatefromgif("./patch.gif");

$white = imagecolorallocate($head, 255, 255, 255);
$purple = imagecolorallocate($head, 200, 0, 200);
imagefilledrectangle($head, 0, 0, 55, 50, $purple);
imagecopy($head, $habbo, 0, 0, 5, 7, 64, 110);
imagecopy($head, $patch, 13, 43, 0, 0, 31, 7);
imagecolortransparent($head, $purple);
header("Content-type: image/gif");
return imagegif($head);
```

Comment: 463 is a Key management Failure. Looks like you're trying to access something in a secured area and your code is not identifying itself properly.

Comment: Is your URL accesible in the browser? 463 is part of 4xx error codes that indicate an error in the way you perform HTTP request.

Comment: I'm trying to pull an image off a site and edit it. Could it be that the site is blocking it for some reason? @Alexei

Comment: I think GeoffAtkins is right. First test would be what I have asked - copy-paste the whole URL in the browser and see if it works. Another thing to try - maybe non-https (http) version works (the browser is also your friend here).

Comment: @Alexei I know that the URL is accessible, but how do you mean by 'non-https'.

Comment: Just to try: http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/ ....

Comment: @Alexei Unfortunately, it just 404's without http (even when I add www.) maybe because it's https.