# HTTP Status Code 463 on js but not on python

Tags: javascript, python, http

I am attempting to extract `html` code from this [website](https://www.corenet.gov.sg/general/e-info.aspx) and it throws the status code 463 Restricted Client when I made a request via javascript code.

Note that the said website can be opened via browser, as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719878/what-does-http-request-failed-http-1-1-463-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
//Using js
const request = require('request');

request('https://www.corenet.gov.sg/general/e-info.aspx', (error, response, html) => {
   console.log(response.statusCode) //Throws 463, HTML not accessibile
})

//Using python
import requests
response = requests.get("https://www.corenet.gov.sg/general/e-info.aspx")
response //Status code 200, able to access HTML
```

Would anybody able to advice why the discrepancy? Ideally, I would like to perform the extraction in js. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably the user agent. Try changing the [`User-Agent` header](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

request.open('GET','https://www.corenet.gov.sg/general/e-info.aspx', (error, 
response, html) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode)
})

request.send();

request.onload = function(){
    var response = request.response
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(response)
    console.log(parsedData)
}
```